# Apache NiFi: failed INSERT statement caused by NOT NULL CONSTRAINT

Tags: sql, postgresql, apache-nifi

I have a JSON

```
{
  "username" : "ChokkiAST",
  "login_date" : "2021-01-15",
  "active": true
}
```

I want to `INSERT` this data into database table with structure:

```
CREATE TABLE web.accounts_activity (
    username text NOT NULL,
    login_date date NOT NULL,
    active bool NULL DEFAULT false,
    id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT web.accounts_activity_username_key UNIQUE (username),
    CONSTRAINT cabinet_account_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

My JSON doesn't contain `id` field because database should auto generate values (I perform transffering from Spring JPA code). I tried with `PutDatabaseRecord` with `INSERT` statement and I got the error: `CONSTRAINT ERROR: value NULL at column "id"`. Tried with `UPSERT` statement - same error.

Also I tried to use `PutSQL` processor with following SQL script (values from attributes):

```
INSERT INTO web.accounts_activity (username, login_date, active, id)
VALUES (${username}, ${login.date}, ${is.active}, DEFAULT);
```

And I got the error:

```
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

So, how to exactly insert this `id` with Apache NiFi?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `id` completely from the lists of columns and values. It will auto-generate a value, this is how `serial` works.

```sql
INSERT INTO web.accounts_activity (username, login_date, active)
VALUES (${username}, ${login.date}, ${is.active});
```

Comment: It didn't help. Still got error: `ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block`

Comment: Could it be aborted by the previous DB operation?

Comment: I tried to add this through DBeaver and it works fine, no errors. Seems like Apache NiFi doing smth wrong.